# Go slice stored in dynamic memory or static memory

Tags: go, memory-management, slice

I was searching for memory allocations of slices whether static at compile time or dynamic on fly. Since slices are pointers to the array in back and I have studied that for dynamic memory allocation, pointers are crucial. So what is the allocation of slice and how about maps.

Comment: Both slices and arrays are allocated at runtime. Whether they are allocated on the heap or stack may vary though (based on escape analysis).

Comment: @icza is there any go reference for that. does `make` works like `new` to allocate space for slices.

Comment: Never confuse `make` with `new`. `new` returns a pointer to the zero value of the type passed. `make` returns a non-pointer to an initialized structure.

Comment: This blog should tell you everything you want to know about how slices are implemented in Go https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Implicitly it is the consequence of this: arrays, slices and their elements are addressable, you can take their (memory) address. A valid memory address only exists at runtime, so slices / array cannot be allocated at compile time.

Comment: @FranckJeannin Nothing here is written about memory allocation to runtime or compile time. It is only telling the usage of slices.

Comment: The missing link here is understanding that 'make' does the (dynamic) allocation. Slices can grow and are garbage collected so compile-time allocation doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @icza:  "slices and their elements are addressable" `string`s are immutable, so they are a special case.

Comment: @peterSO Yes, `string` is implemented using a (read-only) byte slice, but the `string` type is not a slice type, `reflect.TypeOf("").Kind()` returns a different kind than `reflect.TypeOf([]byte{}).Kind()`.

Comment: @peterSO Please I am confused a little. Can anyone elaborate as an answer that would be really helpful.

Comment: ,@icza: "slices and their elements are addressable". Since `strings` are immutable, `string` and therefore slice of `string`, elements are not addressable. : `s := "string"; p := &s[0];` error `cannot take the address of s[0]` and `s := "string"[0:1]; p := &s[0]` error `cannot take the address of s[0]`.

Comment: @Himanshu: If you were allowed to obtain a pointer to an element of a `string` you could change the value of the element. But, `string`s are immutable, so that is not allowed.

Comment: @peterSO `"string"[0:1]` is not a slice, it's a (sub)string. Similarly, `&s[0]` would be taking the address of an index expression indexing a _string_, not a _slice_ (even though in the background it will index the byte slice of the string).

Comment: @icza seems like I am also looking at the way that peter is taking string variable not slice of strings. I have a query that slice it self is a pointer to first index of array of elements. Then why to take address of element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

The slice descriptor is a `struct`. `make([]type, len, cap)` returns a `slice` descriptor with a pointer to an underlying array with the given `type`, `len` (length), and `cap` (capacity). The slice descriptor and/or its underlying array are allocated on the stack and/or the heap.

```
type string struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
}
```

The string descriptor is a `struct` with a pointer to an underlying `byte` array with length `len`. Since `strings` are immutable, the capacity is redundant; it is always equal to the length. The string descriptor, from a literal or conversion, and/or its underlying array are allocated on the stack and/or the heap.

Consider a string as a special form of a `byte` slice. For example, slice expressions apply to both.

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)
>
> Slice expressions construct a substring or slice from a string, array,
>   pointer to array, or slice. There are two variants: a simple form that
>   specifies a low and high bound, and a full form that also specifies a
>   bound on the capacity.